# Set value of object using function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set the value of a named object key `SORT` with a function, like this:

```
  statementPdfs.push ({
      NAME: currFile.getName(), 
      ID: currFile.getId(), 
      BLOB: currFile.getBlob(), 
      MIME_TYPE: currFile.getBlob().getContentType(),
      URL: currFile.getUrl(),
      SORT:  () => {
         let dates = currFile.getName().match(/(\w+)\s(\d+)/);
         return (dates[2]+
              (dateNums[dates[1].toUpperCase()] < 10
                  ? "0"+dateNums[dates[1].toUpperCase()]
                  : dateNums[dates[1].toUpperCase()]
               )
         );
      }
  });
```

...but the returned value for the `SORT` property is the function and not the `return` value. Sure there must be a simple answer, but it eludes me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need what is called an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE): wrap the function in `(.....)()`:

```
SORT: (() => {
    let dates = currFile.getName().match(/(\w+)\s(\d+)/);
    return (dates[2]+
          (dateNums[dates[1].toUpperCase()] < 10 
               ? "0"+dateNums[dates[1].toUpperCase()] 
               : dateNums[dates[1].toUpperCase()]
          )
    );
})()
```

Unrelated, but you can prepad with a zero using `padStart`:

```
SORT: (() => {
    let dates = currFile.getName().match(/(\w+)\s(\d+)/);
    return dates[2]+dateNums[dates[1].toUpperCase()].padStart(2, "0");
})()
```